# Screenshots for AppStore - do I combine into one image?

Tags: app-store, itunes, screenshot

ITunes Connect has different buttons for uploading screenshots (e.g. one for 3.5 inch retina)
Can I use each button more than once to upload more than one screenshot - or will a second upload overwrite the first? I know it says "screenshots" (plural) but it is not clear whether that is because I need to combine several screenshots into one image and upload it. Especially since the available sizes seem to be larger than the default screenshot size that XCode produces.

Comment: If sizes is the issue, try appscreenies.com . They provide screenshots for all sizes

Answer (score 0):

OK. Found the answer by taking a plunge and just trying it. Yes, you can add a number of screenshots under each category. They are displayed for you, and it seems that you can change them later as well. So it is really easy.